# Evaluating limit involving logarithm

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, analysis, limits, matrix-calculus

[image]

> I understand why (24) and (25) are true, but did not understand why
>   (26) is true? For full details please see the following [paper](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1751-5823.2001.tb00457.x)

Comment: Link is behind a paywall.

Comment: @ncmathsadist I was unable to find a link without a paywall, but I've attached the relevant Theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{a}\sum_{t=1}^Tx_t^2\right)=\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{a}\sum_{t=1}^T2^{2(t-1)}\right)=\ln(1)-\ln(a)+\ln \sum_{t=1}^T2^{2(t-1)}=0-\ln(a)+\prod_{t=1}^T2\ln2^t-\prod_{t=1}^T2\ln4=2T\ln2 + \mathcal{O}(1)$